# How can I delete similar element from a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to delete similar elements from a list within a specific range while keeping the original element.

Example:

```py
Line = [208.2, 208.1, 208.17, 214.5]

#check the points within Lines
for i in range(0,len(Line)):
   if not min(Line) == Line[i]:
       # points are removed based on following formula
      if (Line[i]-(Line[i]*float(0.005))<=min(Line)<=Line[i]+(Line[i]*float(0.005))):
           if not Line[i]==[] and Line[i] in Line:
               Line[i] = 0

Line = [i for i in Line if i != 0]
```

Expected output:

```py
[208.2, 214.5]
```

Actual output:

```py
[208.1, 208.17, 214.5]
```

Comment: How do you define similar elements?

Comment: Your array example doesnt contain similar elements so you have to be more specific. Similar numbers before the decimal point?

Comment: @python_user, 208.2 and 208.1 differ by ±0.1 and not by ±0.005  so...

Comment: it is `* 0.005` so `+-` half a percent?

Comment: Do you care if the result is `[208.17, 214.5]` vs `[208.2, 214.5]`?

Comment: min = Line[i]-(Line[i]*float(0.005))    max = Line[i]+(Line[i]*float(0.005)). If Number lies within min and max it is considered as similar.

Comment: @JonSG it does not matter result from these two [208.17, 214.5] vs [208.2, 214.5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to address this problem would be to sort the input then loop over the sorted items comparing the current item to the prior item and if there was a difference above your threshold, add the prior one to a result list.

I have not tested this, but I think this might do it:

```
Line = sorted([208.2, 208.1, 208.17, 214.5])

results =[]
prior = Line[0]
for curr in Line[1:]:
    if abs(curr - prior) > prior * 0.005:
        results.append(prior)
    prior = curr
results.append(prior)

print(results)
```